# How to prevent cache with date/hour got from PHP?

Tags: php, no-cache

I'm showing the date and hour in the website header, this date/hour get from a data base MySQL, these change every time, twice daily. The problem is that it shows  an earlier date, i.e., one or two days before in the browser. How to prevent this?. I've tried to do this between header tag, but this wasn't the solution:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />   
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: When it shows the old date, does a hard refresh fix it?

Comment: That's right, and this I want to avoid

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347595/htaccess-how-to-force-the-clients-browser-to-clear-the-cache

Comment: You need to check the caching headers the server is sending rather than the cache meta tags in the page content.