# Angular 2 see changes in a published new app update

Tags: angular, web-hosting

Currently, I have angular 2 app running and working great on a shared web hosting.

I'm using angular 2 cli and I upload my `dist` folder whenever I make changes.

When I access my app after making changes and uploadidng the new `dist` content, I see the old version - without any changes. 
When I Accessing the app from Spy Mode (CTRL+SHIFT+N) in Chrome, I see the new version.

I assume that need to delete the cache every time making changes to angular 2 app, so the browser will reload the new version.

Is there any way to make it reload the app whenever I'm making changes and uploading a new app version?

I do not wish to make a notice to my visitors to refresh the browser cache in order to see a new version..

Answer (score 1):

Add a version number to the URL and make the client check the version regularly and make it redirect itself to the new URL when it detects a new version.

See also [htaccess - How to force the client's browser to clear the cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347595/htaccess-how-to-force-the-clients-browser-to-clear-the-cache)

Comment: Thanks. It looked good at first, but then I was thinking about making a new URL for each upgrade - and it's not a great solution. If google already indexes my website URL - it will have to index each new url every time I'm upgrading which makes this solution really bad for SEO. Although it gave me some idea.. will adding a version number to the main,js file and updating index.html with the new file route may work? *edit*: Seem like there is no reference to the main.js in the` index.html` \:

Comment: AFAIK adding some query parameter also makes the browser to reload and keeps the URL the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found this as a good solution. He has a script that is run on every release that creates a version.json that is checked every so often and if that file changes it reloads the app (or whatever you want it to do).

https://blog.nodeswat.com/automagic-reload-for-clients-after-deploy-with-angular-4-8440c9fdd96c