# Force re cache .js files or preferably one file

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, caching

I have a js file which cannot be renamed as it's used by users who add a bookmarklet to their browsers. The js file is called from the bookmarklet.

I cache all js files on my site using cache-control within htaccess file.

So if I make a change to the js file in question, can i somehow force a users machine to recache that file?

Is there anything I can do within htaccess or anything like that?

New to me this...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347595 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207492

Answer (score 1):

I'd set a `Cache-Control: max-age=86400` instead of an expiry date if you're updating the file often.

But if you would do planned weekly deployments, you could set an `Expires:` header which points to a time at the end of the current week, so that it would expire right before your planned deployments, thereby making the browser downloading a new version of the file for all request after that point in time.

Another solution would be to start naming your files with version-numbers or appending query-strings to your bookmarklet JS URL.

Answer (score 0):

In your bookmarklet code you could append, say, current date when including that JS file,

```
http://example.com/included.js?d=2012-11-22
```

and then re-route it in your .htaccess to whatever with a rewrite rule. Thus, you'll have a daily window of opportunity to push changes, without caching suffering much. May be good enough.