# .htaccess - How to clear browser cache?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, caching, mod-rewrite

I had some problems with browser caching. When `css, js, image` files change the content but not the name, we must send to browser to download the new one and discard cached files.

Just pressing F5 or something like this the new files are not being updated.

There is a **way** to **force** browser *forget* the cache and download the new version of files?

Comment: You should change this be a question, and then you should answer it with what you posted here. That's how helpful hints and tutorials work on this site.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll do it..

Answer (score 0):

Some people with this *"issue"*

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347595/htaccess-how-to-force-the-clients-browser-to-clear-the-cache)** and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207492/how-to-force-a-browser-to-refresh-a-cached-version-of-a-webpage)** pages gave me an idea and I want to share it. `:)`. My directory structure is this:

```
website/
   |- libs/
       |- css/
       |- js/
       |- imgs/
   |- system/
   |- site/
   |- .htacces
   |- index.php
```

so, we can use the `.htacces` file to *"fool"* the browser like this:

```
RewriteRule ^libs\.v[0-9]{1,}(.*) libs/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.v[0-9]{1,}\.css$ $1.css
```

And, on `html`files use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="path/to/libs/css/style.v2.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/libs/js/javascripts.v1.js"></script>
<img src="path/to/libs/imgs/logo.v5.png" alt="Logo" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="path/to/libs.v1/css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/libs.v1/js/javascripts.js"></script>
<img src="path/to/libs.v1/imgs/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
```

This is working fine for me.. whem I change something on a file I just `add` or `change` the number after `.v` like: `.v1`, `.v2`

**Reason**: this *trick* make the browser see "http://www.mydomain.com/libs/css/style.v1.css" and than.. the cache/browser will *believe* that is a new file.. `;)`

I hope to help someone.. 
any suggestions will be Welcome